# Generate complete HTML website using the structure of a directory and subdirectories

Tags: html, css, content-management-system, automation

I often have to create a small website, that contains a set of documents (doc, xls, pdf, ppt, ...). The navigation is mostly the same as in the illustration below: chapters -> lessons -> documents. The number of lessons, chapters, documents and types of documents differ. The URL to the document can be the document name (whithout extension) or a custom/definable name per document.

At the moment I do this manually in Dreamweaver which is sometimes quite a job if you're having 100+ documents :)

Now what I want is a sort of tool, that generates me this kind of website, html based, which still gives me the opportunity to add a custom style/css to them. I need some sort of tool that allows me to create a directory structure, add the right files to the right directory, and convert this structure into a (basic) html page. Then afterwards I add a different CSS/Theme to it.

Does anyone has an idea what I can use for this?

[image: structure]

Comment: If you can, number things sequentially then you could use `PHP` or a similar language to generate lists like this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The documents aren't numbered sequentially, it's different for every website.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a tool called Snap2HTML that does the trick for me. However, I would like it to be more tweakable, as in theme-able, but it's a start :) The tool I found is Snap2HTML http://www.rlvision.com/snap2html/

If anyone knows a good alternative, please let me know.